# Confusion in a Proof

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-continuity

The question and its proof are given below:

> $ \text{Page 86, Problem 12} $
>
> $ \color{red}{\text{A function $ f $ is said to be periodic with period $ p $ if $ f(x + p) = f(x) $ for all real $ x $.}\\\text{Prove that if $ f(x) $ is continuous and periodic then it is uniformly continuous on the}\\\text{reals.}} $
>
> $ \qquad \text{Proof: First, since it is continuous on the closed interval $ [0, p] $ it is uniformly}\\\text{continuous on $ [0, p] $:} $
>
> $$ x \text{, } y \text{ in } [0,p] \text{, } \lvert x - y \rvert < \delta \Rightarrow \lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert < \varepsilon $$
>
> $ \qquad \text{Second, if $ x $ and $ y $ are numbers with $ \lvert x - y \rvert < \delta $ then there is an integer such}\\\text{that $ x + jp $ and $ y + jp $ are in $ [0, p] $, and} $
>
> $$ \begin{align}
>        &\lvert x - y \rvert < \delta \Rightarrow \lvert (x + jp) - (y + jp) \rvert < \delta \Rightarrow  
>   \\   &\lvert f(x)- f(y) \rvert =  
>   \\   &\lvert f(x + jp) - f(y + jp) \rvert < \varepsilon
>      \end{align}
>   $$
>
> $ \text{That is,} $
>
> $$ \lvert x - y \rvert < \delta \Rightarrow \lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert < \varepsilon \text{.} $$

However I can not understand why we are sure that there exists an integer $j$ such that $x + jp$ is in the interval $[0,p]$. Could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: Sam's answer is perfect, because it answers the question that was asked. However ... it leaves the basically wrong proof intact, giving OP a chance to realize what a complete mess it is, and even after the main body's corrected, the secondary part involving $jp$ remains flawed in yet another way that OP can learn from. Will this learning actually happen? Who knows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $\frac{x}{p} = [\frac{x}{p}] + \{\frac{x}{p}\}$, where $[\cdot]$ denotes integer part and $\{\cdot\}$ denotes fractional part. Then $\{\frac{x}{p}\} \in [0,1)$, so $x = p \cdot \frac{x}{p} = p[\frac{x}{p}] + p\{\frac{x}{p}\}$. Then take $j=-[\frac{x}{p}]$ and note that $p\{\frac{x}{p}\} \in [0,p]$.

Comment: (+1) Basically, what I was about to write, but better expressed.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks, but it was slightly wrong of me to refer to the division algorithm, so I have amended my answer.

Comment: why u take j by this quantity  and why you are sure that $p {x/p}$ in [0,p]?

Comment: @hopefully Taking $j = -[\frac{x}{p}]$, we get $x + jp = p\{\frac{x}{p}\}$, and, as I mentioned, $\{\frac{x}{p}\} \in [0,1)$, so $p\{\frac{x}{p}\} \in [0,p]$.

Comment: But I think it’s really a little wrong for some example x,y located near p, such as $x=p-\varepsilon$ and $y=p+\varepsilon$, then the proof should extend, i.e. [0,2p].

Comment: @LarryEppes That's a good point about the original proof given here. I was only answering the question posed after that, i.e., why we can find $j$ such that $x + jp \in [0,p]$. Of course, this is easily fixable, as I believe you're saying.

Comment: My professor said that this proof is wrong (proof given in the question ) and the period should be 2T but I did not understand why ....could you clarify this for me please?